# how to convert date format in my sql after `where`

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysqli_query(Db::$link,"
    select * 
    from `ka_fatora`
    where  DATE_format(`date`,'Y')='2017'
");
```

date = I want to select value after converting it to (Y)//
y : year the value in database as 1485921351.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: improved grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below `MySQLi` Query

```
$result = mysqli_query(Db::$link,"
    SELECT * FROM `ka_fatora`
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date), "%Y")='2017'
");
```